# How do I setup freelan in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, vpn, setup, freelan

I cannot find any tutorials online taking me from installation to connecting to the client within Ubuntu. Are there any tutorials I am missing or does anyone know how to setup freelan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Debian instructions should work:  http://www.freelan.org/download.html#debian

(Notice the debian/Ubuntu at the top of the page).  Failing that, you can always compile from source.  I can't find anything else beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and doesn't seem to be possible right now, see: https://github.com/freelan-developers/freelan.debian/issues/1